# Animation triggered by animation on hover using CSS

Tags: css, animation, button

I'm trying to trigger some other buttons (items) to scroll on `object7:hover` from the 'Add' button (`object7`), but it won't seem to trigger it anyways. I'm trying to avoid the use of JavaScript, using only HTML and CSS. The code that I've got can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Dann/udENV/)

Any suggestions?

**Edit**: Perhaps I wasn't clear enough, this is how it should go:

The user hovers 'Settings' => All the items slide from behind 'Settings' => User hovers 'Add'=>

=> Items slide down from behind the 'Add' button

Comment: Thanks to Heskja for editing the question. I'm not yet familiar with posting this sort of thing.

Comment: Your example works great in Chrome, breaks horribly in IE. Pure CSS is going to be very difficult here due to different browsers. What browsers are a *must* for you to support?

Comment: @amn It's supposed to scroll when you hover it.(Not sure what you mean)

Comment: @agrothe atleast Safari, Maxthon(the one I use), Chrome and Firefox. But I can add `-ms-transition`, just in case IE becomes compatible with `transition`. And I can work out a JS version in case the user is viewing in IE

Comment: Thank you @Dann. Afraid I can't help you. Hope you get a good answer though.

Comment: if you are willing to add a JS version for IE then it would seem sensible to just use JS to display on any browser?

Comment: @JamieM23 true, but as I said, I'm trying to use only HTML and CSS. Preferrably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue is that the button won't respond to the hover event.

If you use spans instead, it seems to work. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/udENV/3/) that demonstrates. I didn't bother to get all the elements lined up properly, but you can see the "New" span move as you hover over the "Add" span, which is what I believe you are trying to achieve.

```
<div class="container">
<span class="set">
    <span class="object1">Start</span >
    <span class="object2">Stop</span >
    <span class="object3">Play</span >
    <span class="object4">Pause</span >
    <span class="object5">More</span >
    <span class="object6">Info</span >
    <span class="object7">Add
         <span class="object8">New</span >       
    </span >
    <span class="default">Settings</span >
    </span>
</div>
```

​Edit: div element also works, as do probably others. Seems like the button element is the issue maybe? Unsure as a google search implies any element is valid with the hover pseudo selector, but the button certainly wasn't working in my version of Chrome.

Comment: Apparently the 'New' is placed on top of 'Add'. Suggestions on changing this?